# How do I implement a Class into an ActionListener?

Tags: java, class, user-interface, actionlistener

As the title indicates I am looking to implement an existing class from my Java project into an `ActionListener` class. To help you understand my issue, I will first explain the scenario:

I have been assigned to create a Graphics package; this will take user input from a **CommandPanel** `JTextField` to draw specified lines from the user when the conditional action has been met and completed. The GUI consists of 4 classes, 3 of which `extend JPanels`.

The problem that I have is trying to implement the specified `GraphicsPanel` class into my `CommandPanel` `ActionListener`.

I want to be able to draw a line when the requirement has been met to ensure that the line is drawn in the same GraphicsPanel as viewed in my main class (not included here).

The statement `gp` works as intended in the `public CommandPanel(GraphicsPanel gp)` segment however when I try to call `gp` into my `ActionListener` to draw a line in that panel, it fails to recognise it as a pre-existing class.

Further clarification can be made to ensure that you understand the problem at hand; any help would be greatly appreciated. :-D

Comment: Make a Constructor for your `ButtonListener` class that takes the `GraphicsPanel` as an argument for the constructor, and store that reference in the class itself to modify it.

Comment: Thank you @Orin , I am currently working on it now as I am still getting to grasps with different methods :-D.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to store gp as a instance variable in your CommandPanel when the constructor is called:

```
private GraphicsPanel gp;
public CommandPanel(GraphicsPanel gp) {
    this.gp = gp;
}
```

Alternatively, hand down gp to the ActionListener and store it in a instance variable in there:

```
public CommandPanel(GraphicsPanel gp) {
    ButtonListener listener = new ButtonListener(gp);
}

public class ButtonListener implements ActionListener {
    GraphicsPanel gp;
    public ButtonListener(GraphicsPanel gp){
        this.gp = gp;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello @xxtesaxx I have tried that, and whilst it does recognise the code as valid, the `gp.drawLine(Color.BLACK, 0, 100, Integer.parseInt(inputelements[1]), 100);` still won't draw the line inside that class. It will only draw the line in the `public CommandPanel` segment. I will keep working on it until I am successful, thank you. :-D

Comment: I don't quiet understand your problem. So you want to draw something in the GraphicsPanel you pass the CommandPanel as the constructor argument, right? Or do you want to draw in a different GraphicsPanel?

Comment: Sorry, I want to draw a line in the actionPerformed segment of code, whilst this is valid:  `public class ButtonListener implements ActionListener {
     GraphicsPanel gp;
     public ButtonListener(GraphicsPanel gp){
         this.gp = gp;
         gp.drawLine(Color.BLACK, 0, 100, 100, 100);
     }` It is in the wrong section, I ideally would like it to go here:

Comment: If you can call drawLine on gp in your constructor, it should as well by storing the go as a instance variable and call drawLine on it later. Have you tried an anonymous action listener? 

commandInput.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){ ... gp.drawLine() ... });

Comment: Have you tried to debug your code to validate that the gp is actually the right one at runtime and that it is correctly stored in the instance variable?

Comment: Maybe there is an exception thrown at runtime? You should add some logging to check that the code is actually executed without errors. :)

Comment: ... I want the code to be instantiated when the if condition within the actionPerformed segment has been met. In this case the line will be drawn inside the GraphicsPanel when the user has entered "forward 100" inside the JTextField. The ActionListener works up to the point where the line needs to be drawn

Comment: So whats the outcome of this? Have you fixed it? Did saving the gp as a instance variable finally solved your issue or have you found a different way of doing it? I'd really like if you'd chose my answer as correct ;P

Comment: After consulting with my Java tutor, I managed to find an answer. You were spot on although visibility was an issue (hence why the code didn't appear to work); we fixed this by adding another class and called the gp class. We used your recommendation for `this.gp=gp` and the outcome is looking promising thus far; thank you for your help :-D

Comment: Glad to help. :) Could you accept the answer so this question is gets marked as finished? By the way, you can access the outer classes instance variables from inner classes but for better reusability, you could put the button listener in its own class. Then you need to pass the gp down to the listener via its constructor and save it in an instance variable inside the button listener.